How to debug a merged assembly (.EXE)?
I'm using ILRepack to merge $(TargetDir)\*.dll with $(TargetDir)\Setup.exe into a subfolder $(TargetDir)\Merged\Setup.exe. The merge is successful, and Setup.exe runs, but I'm getting some JIT errors that don't occur during a debug run and I need to... well... debug them.
But when I attach to the process, Visual Studio's Modules window reports that the "Binary was not built with debug information." So I can't load the symbols.
I'm doing this in Debug configuration, and a .PDB is being generated. But it seems the assembly itself is missing something.
There's this question, but the scenario is different: I'm not using Plugin Replay (I'm also not sure what that is; it appears to be something related to Dynamics 365).
Mine is just plain-ol' generic stuff. No external dependencies or complications. I just need to get at those JIT errors.
Is there a way to get ILRepack to include debug information during the merge, so I can load the .PDB?

How exactly are you merging these assemblies? You say you have PDBs - but those will be for each original separate assembly file - (AFAIK) they can't be used as-is with merged assemblies (because things like offsets, addresses, and file hashes will all be completely different).

Also, what version of .NET are you targeting? Since .NET Core, .exe files are not .NET assemblies anymore: now they're just native-code launchers for the CLR and your assembly is now in a separate .dll file - R.I.P. single .exe file toy projects.

I'm targeting net48, using the ILRepack MSBuild task. The CLI syntax is ILRepack /out:Merged\Setup.exe <assemblies to merge>, similar to the old ILMerge. You're correct that the individual pre-merge PDBs can't be used; they aren't. ILRepack is producing a singe .PDB alongside the newly merged Setup.exe, but the assembly itself is built without debugging information.

"R.I.P. single .exe file toy projects"

There are different kinds of PDB files that net48 supports (full, portable, etc) - I'd be surprised if ILRepack supports all of them - it's possible one of your projects is using a different PDF format and that might be breaking it?

I've never fiddled with PDB formats, so I believe it's safe to say that they're all the same. That said, I should have a repro project ready in a couple of days in case you'd like to have a go at it (I'm busy tomorrow on other stuff).

It turned that out my own operations were the source of the problem.
I was modifying resources in the merged assembly, which of course was breaking the match between it and its .pdb file.
